# Analytical Geometry Techniques to sketch curves?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, analytic-geometry, book-recommendation

What are some books that illustrate or teach the techniques to sketch the graph of such curves as listed below, analytically or elsewise *without manually putting and values for x and then finding out y.*

- |x| + |y| = 1

> **My attempt**: We can write this as $|y| = 1 - |x|.$
> If $y \geqslant 0,$ $y = 1 - |x|$ and if $y < 0$ then $y = |x| - 1.$
>
> Thus, combining both we get a diamond shaped curve with both horizontal vertices having two intersecting lines each, since $1-|x|$ is the upside down curve of $|x|$ shifted 1 unit up on Cartesian plane and $|x| - 1$ is the regular $|x|$ V curve shifted 1 unit downwards.

Now if one plots $|x| + |y| = 1$ with desmos or any other curve sketching tool, it is quickly evident that what I wrote above isn't correct. Since $|x| + |y| = 1$ is simply a diamond centered at the origin **but without** any extra arms lying at the horizontal vertices.

- $|y| = \sin (x)$

> Similar to the previous one, considering $|y|$ branch wise for $y \geqslant 0$ and $y < 0$ gives two functions and combining them result in a intersecting curve of $- \sin (x)$ and $\sin (x).$

Again, this is incorrect since when $|y| = \sin (x)$ is plot using desmos, the curve has gaps between certain intervals.

- $y = \frac{x^2 + 1}{x^2 - 1}$ and \begin{equation*}
      f(x) = \begin{cases}
                \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}(x - \lfloor x \rfloor )\right)& \text{if } \lfloor x \rfloor \text{ is odd }, x \geqslant 0, \\
                  \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4}(1 - x + \lfloor x \rfloor )\right) & \text{if } \lfloor x \rfloor \text{ is even }, x \geqslant 0.
            \end{cases}
  \end{equation*}

> I fail to come up with anything for rational functions or such piecewise function.

etc. To add a few more examples $(x+y)^{2} = xy^{2},$ $|y| = \sin(x^2)
,$ $y= e^{x}(2x^{2} - 5x +2),$ $ y = 7|x|-|x|^3.$

So what are some references I can study to tackle such questions ? What is basics behind analytically sketching such curves (without a digital sketching tool of any sorts of course).

If such texts doesn't exist, can I get some insight on where I am going wrong with my attempts ?

Comment: This question is not really about **[real-analysis]**, so I think you should remove that tag.  Additionally, I think you should include the tags **[reference-request]** and **[book-recommendation]**.

Comment: Curve sketching is often treated in chapters entitled " Graphing functions" . Graphs of rational functions in " Rational functions" chapters. Nice and reader friendly explanations in Blitzer's *College Algebra*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not have my copy of the book available with me right now, but I think [Fuller's **Analytic Geometry**](https://www.lazada.com.ph/products/authentic-analytic-geometry-fourth-edition-1973-gordon-fuller-i589062325-s1611134149.html?exlaz=d_1:mm_150050845_51350205_2010350205::12:12598959962!121452561322!!!pla-297612067635!c!297612067635!1611134149!135757873&gclid=CjwKCAiA4veMBhAMEiwAU4XRr3cOQ4QVoA2kdJj-mc4s9BGM0p6dx24CZRafhk0KhS-xn_qHdRNIWBoCAS8QAvD_BwE) textbook is just what you need.

Or you might find suitable graphing methods in [Love and Rainville's **Analytic Geometry**](https://www.lazada.com.ph/products/analytic-geometry-by-love-and-rainville-original-i280518502-s426878497.html?exlaz=d_1:mm_150050845_51350205_2010350205::12:12598959962!121452561322!!!pla-1455702876689!c!1455702876689!426878497!494535758&gclid=CjwKCAiA4veMBhAMEiwAU4XRr6wguvcDktnnZ5iwMXQXdwR-yyzX8ymvUj7fpKZ_RSCMJeGVhBuIdhoC3TIQAvD_BwE) textbook.

Both textbooks cover graphical methods to a considerable detail.

Comment: I see, I will try to get a hold of them.

P.S. I did have the reference request tag, wasn't aware of the book-recommendation tag. Thanks!